# How do I make a validation with usestate()?

Tags: reactjs, axios

So I got

```
  const [Error, setError] = useState("");
```

I want it so that if updateDeveloper submits correctly, there should be a green confirmation text below it.

```
const updateDeveloper = (id) => {
  Axios.put(`${url}/update`, { slack_id: newSlackID, id: id }).then(
    (response) => {
      setdeveloperList(
        developerList.map((val) => {
          return val.id === id
            ? {
                id: val.id,
                slack_id: newSlackID,
                name: val.name,
                selected: val.selected,
                absent: val.absent
              }
            : val;

          
        })
      );
    }
  );
  };
```

OnClick the button will UPDATE a value. I need it so that if that button is clicked, that the updateDeveloper works correctly and gives out a useState "Submitted Correctly!" I already had something like this

```
<button onClick={() => { updateDeveloper(val.id); }}>Update</button>
<h1>{updateDeveloper ? {Error} : {NoError}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding `try/catch` is enough for what you're trying to do here. You should also consider adding a loading state. Check out the following:

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState();
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState();

  const updateDeveloper = async (id) =>  {
      try{
         setIsLoading(true);            
         setSuccessMessage('');
         setErrorMessage('');

         // Call your API
         const response = await Axios.put(`${url}/update`, { slack_id: newSlackID, id: id });
         
         // handle the response
         setdeveloperList(...)
    
        // at this point you're successful and can do something like
        setSuccessMessage(`successfully updated developer ${id}`);
  
      } catch (err) {
           setErrorMessage('something went wrong');
      } finally {
           setIsLoading(false);
      }
   }

   return (
       <button onClick={() => { updateDeveloper(val.id); }}>Update</button>

       { errorMessage && <h1>{ errorMessage }</h1> }

       { successMessage && <h1>{ successMessage }</h1> }
   )
```

Comment: Yeah this has helped me out a lot, thank you. Works smoothly